# How to call someone else's contract in truffle console?

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I want to call methods on someone else's contract in truffle console, so not the usual migrate/deploy. How to do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the contract code, you can do that using the Ethereum explorer for the relevant testnet or mainnet.
2. Create an empty truffle project: "truffle init"
3. Place the contract code into a file in contracts dir, eg: contracts/Code.sol
4. Compile it: "truffle compile", this will create .json file under build/contracts for every contract you compiled
   4b. You may need to change the version of solc compiler in truffle config file, check the pragma declaration in the code.
5. "truffle console" loads the contract definitions when it starts, so you can do:

let c = await Code.at('0x123XYZ')